# C# preview form controls

Tags: c#, winforms, preview

Is it possible to display C# winform controls in a print preview? I'm going to display a form generated in C# winforms in a print preview mode, what are my options?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: search in google and other search engine for drawing form on printDocument in C#

Answer (score 0):

Programatically, you can take a screenshot of your screen when form is visible and show the image in print preview.

Comment: I'm thinking about it, but how can I display something in my print preview control? I've tested it but it seems there is no way to give it something to display? can you give me some code?